# Image has disappeared from display, but it's there

Tags: html, css

I decided to try out the new program called Scarlet by Macaw. I set up a page and all went well, however when I moved the code into Dreamweaver, an image has disappeared. I have fiddled with this for a couple hours now and I'm pulling my hair out. It's something basic, I think the lack of a z-index, however giving it one has not changed the issue. The CSS is in the page itself, since it's a one-page deal. 
The missing image is the UPS logo, located next to the other client logos, last in line. I'd give you a line number, but there aren't any  :(

Can some kind soul please tell me what I am missing?

```
    <!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0">
<title>index</title>

 <style type="text/css">
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    src: <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,600,700,800' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    font-weight: 400;
    font-style: normal;
}

h1  {
color: #FFFFFF;
font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
font-size: 18px;
font-weight: bold;
line-height:2;
margin-top: 30px;
margin-bottom: 1px;
}

h2  {
color: #FFFFFF;
font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
font-size: 16px;
font-weight: normal;
line-height:1.38;
margin-top: 0px;
margin-bottom: 0px;
}

h3  {
color: #000000;
font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
font-size: 18px;
font-weight: bold;
line-height:1.38;
margin-top: 30px;
margin-bottom: 1px;
}

h4  {
color: #000000;
font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
font-size: 16px;
font-weight: normal;
line-height:1.38;
margin-top: 0px;
margin-bottom: 0px;
}

 .fluid-span-1 {
  width: 6.5%;
}

.fluid-span-2 {
  width: 15%;
}

.fluid-span-3 {
  width: 23.5%;
}

.fluid-span-4 {
  width: 32%;
}

.fluid-span-5 {
  width: 40.5%;
}

.fluid-span-6 {
  width: 49%;
}

.fluid-span-7 {
  width: 57.5%;
}

.fluid-span-8 {
  width: 66%;
}

.fluid-span-9 {
  width: 74.5%;
}

.fluid-span-10 {
  width: 83%;
}

.fluid-span-11 {
  width: 91.5%;
}

.fluid-span-12 {
  width: 100%;
}

.fluid-offset-1 {
  margin-left: 8.5%;
}

.fluid-offset-2 {
  margin-left: 17%;
}

.fluid-offset-3 {
  margin-left: 25.5%;
}

.fluid-offset-4 {
  margin-left: 34%;
}

.fluid-offset-5 {
  margin-left: 42.5%;
}

.fluid-offset-6 {
  margin-left: 51%;
}

.fluid-offset-7 {
  margin-left: 59.5%;
}

.fluid-offset-8 {
  margin-left: 68%;
}

.fluid-offset-9 {
  margin-left: 76.5%;
}

.fluid-offset-10 {
  margin-left: 85%;
}

.fluid-offset-11 {
  margin-left: 93.5%;
}

body {background-color:#999999;
    font-size:1em;
}

.about{
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    clear: both;
    width: 100%;
    height: 240px;
    background-image: url(images/backgrounds/lt_gray.png);
    background-size: auto auto;
}

.blurb {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;left:17%;
    width:33%;
    height:283px;
}

.blurb2 {
    float:left;
    width:50%;
    height:239px;
    margin-left:40.9492199999%;
}

.clients {
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    clear:both;
    width:33%;
    height:100px;
    margin:400px 0 0 17%;
}

.content{
    position: absolute;
    top: 100px;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 4;
    width: 100%;
    height: 500px;
    background-image: url(images/backgrounds/dk_gray.png);
    background-size: auto auto;
    background-position: left top;
}

.facebook {
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:-0.2588757397%;
    width:25px;
    height:auto;
    overflow:hidden;
    z-index:5;
}

.form {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;left:51.8333333333%;
    width:33%;
    height:350px;
}

.google {
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;left:143px;
    width:25px;
    height:auto;
    overflow:hidden;
    z-index:8;
}

.header {
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    width:100%;
    height:100px;
    background-color:#999999;
}

.image {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top:26px;           
    left: 20.06640625%;
    width: 196px;
    height: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    top: 25px;
}

.linkedin {
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:95px;
    width:25px;
    height:auto;
    overflow:hidden;
    z-index:7;
}

.logo {
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    top:28px;
    left:17%;
    width:250px;
    height:auto;o
    verflow:hidden;
}

.pepsi {
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:23.6229482323%;
    width:100px;
    height:auto;
    overflow:hidden;
    z-index:11;
}

.social {
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    width:15%;
    height:25px;
    margin:436px 0 0 12.79948%;
}

.twitter {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 46px;
    width: 25px;
    height: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: 6;
}

.ups {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    width: 100px;
    height: auto;
    margin-left: 1.9847%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.verizon {
    display:block;
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    z-index:12;
    width:100px;
    height:auto;
    margin-left:47.32086%;
    overflow:hidden;
}

._3m{display:block;position:absolute;top:0;left:0;z-index:10;width:100px;height:auto;overflow:hidden;}

.copywrite{
    float: left;
    clear: both;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #999999;
}

.copywrite{
    float: left;
    clear: both;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #999999;
}

.copywrite-2 {
    position:absolute;
    top:850px;left:17%;
    width:39%;
    min-height:25px;
    line-height:1.38;
    color: #000000;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: normal;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}

 </style>
</head>
<body class="body page-index clearfix">
  <div class="header"> <a href="http://www.issuetrak.com/"><img src="images/logo--trans.gif" alt="IssueTrak" class="logo"></a>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="blurb"><h1>TRACK COMPLAINTS AND COMPLIMENTS</h1>
      <h2>Working with customers, you're guaranteed at least one complaint. But if you're tracking and resolving those complaints with IssueTrak, you may end up with more than one compliment!                 With IssueTrak, ensure faster customer response times and better quality control by centralizing your customer feedback!</h2>
      <br>
      <h1>SIMPLIFY THE PROCESS</h1>
      <h2>
        <ul>
          <li>Resolve issues by email or web portal</li>
          <li>Mobile access</li>
          <li>Easy to use and configure </li>
          <li>Award-winning Support Team</li>
        </ul>
      </h2></div>
    <div class="form"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="clients clearfix">
    <img src="images/client_logos/pepsi.png" alt="Pepsi uses Issuetrak" class="pepsi">
    <img src="images/client_logos/3M.png" alt="3M uses Issuetrak" class="_3m">
    <img src="images/client_logos/verizon.png" alt="Verizon uses Issuetrak" class="verizon">
    <img src="images/client_logos/ups.png" alt="UPS uses Issuetrak" class="ups">
  </div>
  <div class="social">
    <img src="images/social/gplus.png" alt="Find us on Google+" class="google">
    <img src="images/social/li.png" alt="Find us on LinkedIn" class="linkedin">
    <img src="images/social/t.png" alt="Find us on Twitter" class="twitter">
    <img src="images/social/fb.png" alt="Find us on Facebook" class="facebook">
  </div>
  <div class="about clearfix">
    <img src="images/Dan.jpg" alt="Dan Luhring - CEO" class="image" id="dan">
    <div class="blurb2"><h3>Welcome to IssueTrak</h3><br>
    <h4>IssueTrak is a fast-paced, agile software company based in the Hampton Roads area of
Virginia. We’ve a got a 20-year track record of successfully developing issue-tracking
and process management software for companies of all sizes. 

We’re stoked on innovation and we love data, and we’re harnessing the power of both to
develop a next generation product. We are a customer-centric company with a dedicated
vision of creating the most robust and versatile software solution for our clients.
And, we aren’t afraid to take risks to make this happen.</h4></div>
  </div>
  <footer class="copywrite"><span class="copywrite-2">&copy;2015 Issuetrak, Inc. All Rights Reserved</span></footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Ok, Look at your <img> tags in code and find src and then create that folders .<br /> For example <img src="image/about/one.jpg" /> create new folder image then about and then put an image with one.jpg name on there

Comment: Are you sure you’re doing the `src: <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,600,700,800' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>` correctly?

Comment: I don't have a font issue. My font is displaying properly. All of my code for the entire page is above. There are no external files. Any questions you have about elements can be answered there.

Answer (score 0):

The code is ok.
Make sure that the image is in the `images/client_logos/`  folder. Also make sure that the image name and extension are `ups.png`.

Comment: it is. And you can see the image placement in the file. Dreamweaver shows a popup and the image is there. The code is not ok.

Answer (score 0):

Use Chrome Dev Tools and right click one of the visible logos and use "Inspect Element",  then find the UPS image element in Dev tools.   Look at the CSS for clues as to why it's not showing up.  Is the display set to none?   Does it have a height and width?  etc...

Zoom Out may also reveal the image indicating a layout issue.  You can also click the image link from dev tools to make sure that it is there.   Or check the network tab to make sure the image is loading and if not get a clue there as to why from the status code.

You may also want to make sure that any external CSS or JS files are loading and not 404ing.

Let me know if this helps and what you find out and if it has not resolved your issue, I will see what else I can figure out.

Comment: I have done the inspect element thing, and the image shows as there. The path and the holder for it are clearly visible. There are no external files of any kind. Dreamweaver shows the image there in a popup when you pass over the img tag. 
As for your questions, the css is within the file. The relevant part is .ups of the css portion. The display is not set to none. Here is the specific portion of the css code posted above that deals with this image:

.ups {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    width: 100px;
    height: auto;
    margin-left: 1.9847%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

Comment: In Dreamweaver's Design Mode you can see the image is there, however it is not displaying inline with the others. it is on the line below.